# Laravel SPA get user on route that does not require auth middleware

Tags: laravel, authentication, single-page-application

In my controller's construct I specify the middleware:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api')
        ->except(['index', 'show']);
}
```

It's easy to get the user for any routes with the auth middleware by doing:

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->user();
}
```

But I can't work out how to get the user for routes that allow anonymous users to access them and don't use the auth middleware:

```
public function show(Request $request) {
    // $request->user(); - this returns NULL

    // How can I get the user here?
}
```

When I use Chome's inspect network tab I can see this in my request header:

`Authorization:Bearer kGncvh4IlotxIw2zY80GCnQPTMGyPZKGXntsHzsav2DPvffFfZZG60h74rsE`

But what would I need to do to get the user object from this?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out by reading [this blog post](https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51).

The magic line of code is:

```
$user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
```

Comment: Similar to my solution: `app('auth')->guard()->user();`

Comment: That returns null when I try it - but may be helpful for someone else in a different circumstance.

Comment: Could be caused by my default guard is `api`.