# Laravel 5.7 - How to use Auth::check() even when not using auth middleware

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, routes, laravel-middleware

I want to build an API route which can be called by an authenticated user as well as a non-authenticated user and returns the data based on whether or not the user is authenticated.

I am stuck at using Auth::check().

**The controller function is something like this:**

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function check(Request $request) {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            return response()->json([
                        'message' => 'Logged in'
                    ], 200);
        }
        else {
            return response()->json([
                        'message' => 'Not logged in'
                    ], 200);
        }
    }
}
```

I end up having two scenarios:

**Scenario 1**

```
Route::get('scenario1', 'SomeController@check');
```

In this scenario, in the controller when I check Auth::check() inside an if condition I am always getting the false condition, no matter the user is authenticated or not.

**Scenario 2**

```
Route::get('scenario2', 'SomeController@check')->middleware('auth:api');
```

In this scenario, in controller when I check Auth::check() I get true when user is logged in and error(Route[login] not definded) when user is not logged in.

Answer (score 2):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45667563/1780008) by [Felix Eve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967168/felix-eve) :

```
$user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
```

This returns `null` if the user is not authed.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning scenario 2, please read [Protecting Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#protecting-routes) (and the following subsection "Redirecting Unauthenticated Users").

When attaching the `auth` middleware to the route, if the user isn't auththenticated, it is redirected to a route named `login`, which you haven't implemented in your application.

But, I haven't understood why auth seems to work in your scenario 2 but not in your scenario 1…

Comment: I am trying to implement API so I don't want to redirect, after your answer I edited Handler.php to respond with a JSON object with error message 'Unauthenticated'. So now I am not getting the error 'Route[login] not defined' but getting error 'Unauthenticated'. This helped me get a better error message for unauthenticated users but the problem of Auth::check() is still there. I want to allow users to use this route no matter if they are authenticated or not, and still use the Auth facade.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question

> How to use Auth::check() even when not using auth middleware

You simply use `Auth::check()`.  Auth middleware doesn't mean that you always have access to the Auth class, it means that a user must be authenticated to visit / use a particular route.

If you had auth middleware on a route, then did `Auth::check` on the controller method that handled that route, it was always be true, because the middleware has stopped any non authenticated user from reaching that point.

EDIT - You may need to use the web middleware group though.

Comment: That's not my experience: using `Auth::check()` returned `null` for an authenticated user when the route wasn't behind the Auth middleware.